# Jenkins GitHub Pull Request Builder - Status Message

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github-api

I have set up Jenkins to use the GitHub pull request builder.  It's working great!  Except one little thing.  My test suite creates HTML Reports (which I have beautifully posted using the HTML result poster plugin) but I can't seem to change the status message that gets posted to GitHub.  My commits all get marked like:

[image: An image of the status of a successful test run, with a status message of Build finished. No test results found.]

The status of the commit gets updated properly, but the message part always says "Build finished.  No test results found."

I can't seem to figure out how to change this message based on the status of the test suite.  So, basically the only feedback I'm getting is the exit status of my shell script.  This script does all of the building, testing, and handling of results, etc.  This is reasonably acceptable in the event of a pass, but in the event of a failure, this message could be much more helpful!  Even just knowing whether it was a build failure vs. a test suite failure would be nice, so then I can adequately verbally abuse the person who made the pull request :).

Everything else is working so good, that I can't figure out what seems like a trivial change is driving me crazy!  Any ideas?

Comment: Had the same concern and am wondering if anyone managed to solve this.

Comment: Nope.  It's on the back burner.  I'm going to seek out the devs of the plugin some time next week, unless this post happens to get more attention between now and then.

Comment: Same problem here. All is built & tested correctly, but test results don't end up being reported in the PR. Did you learn more already?

Comment: Nope, nothing.  Will post an answer if I find one.  It seems for now it may be a limitation of the extension itself.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, the logic was added here: https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/commit/ffbc581d2712d6b99b9c6d0b081d7895a5ee8039

I believe you just need to generate JUnit formatted test output, and you may or may not need to ad a post-build step to publish the JUnit XML output.

Comment: This is correct, you need to add the "Publish JUnit test result report" Post-build action

Comment: This plugin isn't used to just test java code, so you wont always have a JUnit test result report

Comment: Right, you also need to use a test runner that generates JUnit output.